# The Version of macOS on the selected disk needs to be reinstalled” Error when trying to boot into Ubuntu EFI Disk on a MacbookPro (OS: Monterey)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, mac, macosx

Using this tutorial https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-macos
I get all the way to selecting EFI disk when the MacbookPro gives the error code n the title header.

I’ve also tried to boot from a DVD with Ubuntu 22 on it. Same response. I also used the command line process as outlined in the tutorial. Same result.

Comment: You can't install Ubuntu (or Windows) the normal way in new Apple products with the new Apple Mx chips.

Comment: It’s an older intel mac. Not an M1

Comment: Same problem Macbook Pro i9 15" 2019

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered this error as well, and the solution was to boot into the mac os recovery (hold Apple key and "R" during boot), select the startup security option from the menu bar, and then turn off all boot security.

I did try the medium security setting but still encountered the same issue, only once it was disabled was I able to boot off a USB.

This was the same case on this particular Macbook pro attempting to boot into either windows or Linux off a USB device.